# How to redirect a file as an input to Java program with bash?

Tags: java, bash

My code roughly looks like this:

```
InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
while (true) {
    try {
        String inputStr = null;
        if ((inputStr=bufReader.readLine()) != null) {
            //DO SOMETHING
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("input is null");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

When I run

```
 java -classpath ../src test.TestProgram < filename
```

it process the first line in the file well, but it keeps printing `input is null` and never goes to the second line.

How can I modify my program to to tell it let the error input go and go to the next line?

PS: the file I need to precess is like below:

```
111111111
111111112
111111113
...
```

I tried

```
java -classpath ../src test.TestProgram < filename
echo `cat filename` | java -classpath ../src test.TestProgram
java -classpath ../src test.TestProgram <<< `cat filename`
```

and they all failed

**My fault... I put "BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))" inside the loop... Thanks everybody!**

Comment: Not a direct answer, but FYI readLine() returns null once the end of the original input is reached, therefore once it returns null it will always return null.

Comment: Cuz I still want my java project to take command line input, I dont want to change the source from System.in to file

Comment: The return of null means the end of the original file has been reached.  You can not both use the '<' input redirection, AND give input via stdin.  The redirection operator replaces the terminal standard in with the contents of the file.

Comment: In C++, cin would raise a flag when encounter with error input, and when you do cin.clear() and cin.ignore(), cin is ready for the follow up input. Do we have similar thing in Java?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'error in input'.  Each call to readline will return all the bytes up to but not including a newline/carriage return.  The only time you would get an exception is if the bytes found don't parse correctly given the character set you selected when creating the reader.

Comment: What has this question do do with [bash]? It's about Java and file reading

Comment: I assumed that there maybe exist some ways to change the format or order of "java -classpath ../src test.TestProgram < filename" that could solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is actually fine and it works for me on Mac OSX Java 1.6.0.  I made a few minor changes:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
    while (true) {
      try {
        String inputStr = null;
        if ((inputStr = bufReader.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(inputStr);
        } else {
          System.out.println("input is null");
          return; //end on first null
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
```

I run:

```
java Test.java < data.txt
```

And it outputs:

```
111111111
111111112
111111113
input is null
```

How did you make your input file?  Perhaps your line endings are non-standard?

Here is your code cleaned up a bit:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String inputStr = null;
    try {
      while ((inputStr = bufReader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(inputStr);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("end of file");
  }
```

Comment: My fault... I put "BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))" inside the loop... Thanx!

Answer (score -4):

```
java -classpath ../src test.TestProgram < cat filename
```